# Negative numbers in APDU command

Tags: java, encryption, applet, rsa, javacard

I am writing Java Applet. I need to upload pre-generated `RSAPrivateCrtKey` to applet with APDU Command.

In my computer I am generating key. Next I serialize this key in `privateKeyBuffer`:

```
keyPair = new KeyPair(KeyPair.ALG_RSA_CRT, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_RSA_512);
keyPair.genKeyPair();
rsaPrivateKey = (RSAPrivateCrtKey) keyPair.getPrivate();

byte[] privateKeyBuffer = new byte[165];

short lengthDP1 = rsaPrivateKey.getDP1(privateKeyBuffer, 0);
offset += lengthDP1;

short lengthDQ1 = rsaPrivateKey.getDQ1(privateKeyBuffer, offset);
offset += lengthDQ1;

short lengthP = rsaPrivateKey.getP(privateKeyBuffer, offset);
offset += lengthP;

short lengthQ = rsaPrivateKey.getQ(privateKeyBuffer, offset);
offset += lengthQ;

short lengthPQ = rsaPrivateKey.getPQ(privateKeyBuffer, offset);
```

After generating a buffer I should convert each array element to hex and then send with APDU and last in applet restore my private key, but in `privateKeyBuffer` we have negative numbers :

```
37,65,-96,-110,38,6,-2,73,-37,28,120,-90... (etc)
```

How I should convert them to hex and keep APDU correct (because as I know only positive numbers allowed) or may be there another way to push key to JavaCard?

Any ideas?

Comment: You seem to be providing code for Java Card while you are telling us that "In my computer I am generating key." **Where do you generate the key pair, your smart card or your computer?** Please update your question & titleaccordingly.

Comment: In this example I was generating in my computer and then send keys to card in apdu command

Comment: Because my card doesn't support RSA

Comment: @vojta marked as correct answer I had some thought to add something later and then mark it, but forgot about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply copy your byte array to the APDU buffer and send it. It will work.

```
final byte[] apduBuffer = apdu.getBuffer();
Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(privateKeyBuffer, (short) 0, apduBuffer, (short) 0, (short) privateKeyBuffer.length);
apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, (short) privateKeyBuffer.length);
```

You do not have to think about hex values and positive/negative numbers at all! When you send a byte = 8 bits, you do not deal with its number representation or meaning at all.

---

An extra note:

`byte[] privateKeyBuffer = new byte[165];` is generally a bad idea. You do not need this buffer at all. You can copy key values directly into the APDU buffer, save some persistent memory and make your applet faster.

---

Another note based on dear @Abraham's comment:

The only problem with positive/negative numbers you could face in Java Card is the fact that Java Card `byte` is **signed**, unfortunately. That means its values are always in range [-128,127], although people often forget about it:

```
final byte b = getSomeByteValue(); //from APDU buffer, for example
if (b == 0x80) { //always false!
     //this never happens!
}
```

If you want to understand your `byte` as unsigned (range [0, 255]), you have to cast it to `short` this way:

```
final byte b = getSomeByteValue(); //from APDU buffer, for example
final short unsignedValue = (short) (b & 0xFF);
if (unsignedValue == 0x80) { //correct!
     //can happen
}
```

Comment: I think it's better to mention that he/she need to be worry about the negative/positive numbers only when he wants to compare buffer sections with a number. for example if he want to compare `buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS]` with `129`, he must write `(buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS] & 0x00FF) == 129` instead of `buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS] == 129`. right?

Comment: @Abraham You are absolutely right! I wanted to mention it, but then I was too lazy to write it all down :-). I will improve my answer, thanks.

Comment: `buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS] == 129` is a bad idea anyway, you should create a byte constant `private static final byte INS_SOMETHING = (byte) 0x81;` and compare it to that using just `buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS] == INS_SOMETHING`.

Comment: are all the unsigned numbers should be casted to short ? @vojta

Comment: @Mr.T It depends on range of your values... Byte: -128 to 127. So there are many unsigned values you can safely store as bytes.